# EditText autoscroll doesn't work after showing dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I'm developing an app for users to share their books. To achieve this, I'm getting different data about the book from the user. The problem is, horizontal autoscrolling of all EditTexts are working until Dialog has been shown and dismissed. Once a dialog has been dismissed on the fragment, horizontal autoscrolling of the EditText's on this layout won't work.

I added:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to parent layout of the edittext but doesn't work.

Also to make sure that autoscrolling is enabled I've added:

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

But none of above helped.

Here is XML code of the fragment layout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp25"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp25"
    tools:context=".UI.Fragments.SharePostFragments.Fragment1.OverViewFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_name_of_book"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_semi_bold"
            android:hint="@string/name_of_book"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="50"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font22" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_number_of_characters"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_light"
            android:text="@string/_0_50"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font16"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_name_of_author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/textBoxHeight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp30"
            android:background="@drawable/round_text_box_gray"
            android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_regular"
            android:hint="@string/name_of_writer"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/textBoxHeight"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/round_text_box_border_gray"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_regular"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                android:text="@string/price_of_book"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                android:text="@string/azn_sign"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_price_of_book"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:hint="@string/_0_0"
                android:inputType="text|numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_conditions_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/round_text_box_border_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/textBoxHeight"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:text="@string/book_condition_placeholder"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_button_conditions"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_spinner" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_conditions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_new"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:text="@string/_new"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray_text_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_normal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:text="@string/normal"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray_text_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_old"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:text="@string/old"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray_text_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_languages_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp20"
            android:background="@drawable/round_text_box_border_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/textBoxHeight"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                    android:text="@string/language"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_button_languages"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_spinner" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_languages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp20"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp20"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Java code:

```
package org.kitapp.UI.Fragments.SharePostFragments.Fragment1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import org.kitapp.R;
import org.kitapp.UI.Dialogs.ConditionDialog.ConditionOfBookDialog;
import org.kitapp.UI.Dialogs.LanguageDialog.LanguageDialog;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.OnTextChanged;

public class OverViewFragment extends Fragment implements OverViewContractor.View {

    private final String TAG = OverViewFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private OverViewCallback mListener;

    private OverViewPresenter mPresenter;

    @BindView(R.id.constraint_layout_conditions_root)
    LinearLayout conditionRoot;

    @BindView(R.id.constraint_layout_languages_root)
    LinearLayout languagesRoot;

    @BindView(R.id.linear_layout_conditions)
    LinearLayout conditions;

    @BindView(R.id.root_layout)
    LinearLayout rootLayout;

    @BindView(R.id.text_view_number_of_characters)
    TextView numberOfChars;

    @BindView(R.id.edit_text_name_of_book)
    EditText nameOfBook;

    public interface OverViewCallback {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_over_view, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        new OverViewPresenter(this);

        //rootLayout.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

        return view;
    }

    ////// CONTRACTOR METHODS //////

    @Override
    public void setPresenter(OverViewPresenter presenter) {
        this.mPresenter = presenter;
    }

    ////// LISTENERS //////

    @Override
    @OnClick(R.id.image_button_conditions)
    public void showConds() {
        ConditionOfBookDialog conditionOfBookDialog = new ConditionOfBookDialog(mContext);
        conditionOfBookDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    @OnClick(R.id.image_button_languages)
    public void showLangs() {
        LanguageDialog languageDialog = new LanguageDialog(mContext);
        languageDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @OnTextChanged(R.id.edit_text_name_of_book)
    public void onNameOfBookChange() {
        int len = nameOfBook.getText().toString().trim().length();
        numberOfChars.setText(len + "/50");
        if (len > 50) {
            nameOfBook.setText(nameOfBook.getText().toString().substring(0, 50));
            nameOfBook.setSelection(nameOfBook.getText().length());
        }
    }

    ////// FRAGMENT METHODS //////

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        this.mContext = context;

        if (context instanceof OverViewCallback) {
            mListener = (OverViewCallback) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OverViewCallback");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

}
```

[UI Design and Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTLzX.png)

In the image above, there are EditTexts *Name Of Book* and *Name of Author*. Before showing a dialog, both of them work like a charm. When writing something, the cursor automatically scrolls to the end. Once Dialog has been shown and dismissed, none of them works properly, and the cursor stays at the end of the EditText but still the characters are being written continues in the hidden part.

In this UI it cannot be seen because of the issue, but I've written. 
*Roses are red, violets are blue, Stackoverflow I love u*

But only *Roses are red, violets are blue, Stac* can be seen.

[Weird buggy layout UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ybz.png)

Please, help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, I don't know the underlying reason, but the problem solved once I removed *Butterknife* library from my project.